# Silverlight ListBox Selection is not shown

Tags: silverlight, selection, listboxitem

My individual ListBox has two different ItemTemplates - which gone be chosen by a TemplateSelector.
This works fine and i have two different ItemTmplates shown up on the screen.

But what i dont have instead is a Selection. So i can't select an Item in the ListBox. With the Keyboard it works and you can select one.

Here is what my ContainserStyle looks like:

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyleMain" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Grid x:Name="grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform />
                            </Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To=".35" />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.3" To="1.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.3" To="1.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To=".55" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".75" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor2"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Duration="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="LayoutStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="AfterLoaded"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="BeforeLoaded"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="BeforeUnloaded"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor" Fill="{StaticResource SolidBrushSmarxGreen20}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor2" Fill="{StaticResource SolidBrushSmarxGreen60}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox" />
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                    <CompositeTransform />
                                </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Stroke="{StaticResource SolidBrushSmarxGreen60}" StrokeThickness="1" Visibility="Collapsed" d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

So - as you can see, i have a Selected-State defined.
It's all default styling and Templating - except for the colors.

Thanks in any advice :)

regards
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Found it out - it's really unclear why i don't get a selection. Because when i insert some Items with Content (which i haven't got at the moment), then the selection works fine.
The Selection State works anyway - but you have to click precisely on the Focus Border :)